# Laravel 5.1 Policies in Form Requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'm working on Laravel 5.1, and more specifically the [Authorization](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization) package.

Before this package, I would do all my authorization checks in the `FormRequest::authorize()` method, since this method was designed specifically for authorization checking.

I now want to use the native Authorization package in laravel, which includes Policy files, but I want to use them in the Request file.

This means, as far as I can see, that each form request file needs to be mapped to the policy file.

Surely this cannot be right? If I have 7 main methods in each controller, thats 7 mappings to a single policy file, 1 for each request file. If I then have 20 controllers, thats 140 mappings!

I know I can do that auth check in the controller, and just map the controller, but this seems to be poor implementation on Laravels behalf, otherwise why put the `authorize()` method in the request?

**Question**

In an ideal world, I want to to my policy auth checking before reaching the controller - by doing it in the request. But I don't want to map out each of my request files to a policies.

Is there any way to retrieve the target controller from the request, so that I can just have one mapping - controller -> policy, and reference the controller from the request?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, I've just found out a really easy way to do it, and feel slightly stupid I didn't try it earlier!

In my `AuthServiceProvider` file, I had mapped out each request to the policy file, like this:

```
protected $policies = [
    \App\Http\Requests\Servers\Index::class => Policies\ServerPolicy::class,
    \App\Http\Requests\Servers\Create::class => Policies\ServerPolicy::class,
    \App\Http\Requests\Servers\Store::class => Policies\ServerPolicy::class,
];
```

And then in my authorize() method in the Request, I was doing this:

```
return policy($this)->index();
   or
return policy($this)->create();
```

However, you do not need to pass the object to the policy. Instead you can just pass the class string.

Therefore, I only need to map the controller to the policy:

```
protected $policies = [
    \App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Servers::class => Policies\ServerPolicy::class
];
```

And then just pass the controller class path to the policy function:

```
return policy(\App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Servers::class)->index();
```

So you do not need to pass the mapped object, you can pass the fully qualified class name as a string.